# swiftmailer-bundle symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

i have some problem with swiftmailer in symfony 2.8

## app/config/parameter.yml

```
mailer_transport: mail
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user: xl7061@gmail.com
mailer_password: ******
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_port: 465
```

## app/config/config.yml

```
swiftmailer:
     transport: %mailer_transport%
     encryption: %mailer_encryption%
     port: %mailer_port%
     auth_mode: login
     host: %mailer_host%
     username: '%mailer_user%'
     password: '%mailer_password%'
```

## testController

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject('Requiperation du mot de passe')
                ->setFrom('noreply@ffff-ffff.ff')
                ->setTo($bachelier->getEmail())
                ->setBody(
                    'bonjour,'.$bachelier->getNom()." ".$bachelier->getPrenom().'</br> pour requiperer votre mot de passe click sur le lien suivant : </br> http://site_apres_hebergement/recoverypassword/'.$token
                )
            ;
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

and result :[1 - _profile/Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XK9Q.png) &
[2 - _profile/logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doidy.png)

problem here is: mails don't send, i checked inbox & spam with no result, i already allowed less secure applications" setting enabled

Comment: Try to change `mailer_transport: mail` to `mailer_transport: gmail`

Comment: same issue, nothing there index & spam